# aslactl storing / restoring issues

Tags: sound, alsa

I have a problem with alsa settings not surviving reboot. I have a headless server running 15.04, using sound for shairport-sync.
When I reboot, I get messy alsa settings (volumes). Trying to restore previous configuration gives me strange values. Restoring as super-user works; Restoring as normal user doesn't, unless I specify a file, then it works.

```
$ alsactl restore
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC892" "HDA:10ec0892,1849d892,00100302" "0x1849" "0xd892"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method

$ sudo alsactl restore
[works]

$ alsactl --file ~/asound.state restore
[works too]
```

/var/lib/alsa/asound.state and ~/asound.state should be identical.

Also, I just cannot get restoring after rebooting to work; Currently using rc.local, is that not good?

Comment: Apparently, your user (or whoever `rc.local` is executed as) has no root privileges.

Comment: But all other rc.local-commands work flawlessly…

Comment: Also, I can mute in alsamixer by pressing the "m"-key; But I can't unmute again. Toggles turn back, but no sound returns. I have to unmute via gui in order to get sound back to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't find an actual solution to the problem, but a workaround.

1. Strip the part from `rc.local`
2. Save alsa-config to file: `alsactl --file ~/.asound.state store`
3. Edit `/etc/init.d/shairport-sync` by adding `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/alsactl --file /home/[username]/.asound.state restore` after `do_start() {`

Now, everytime `shairport-sync` is started, volumes will be reset, and since it get's started on boot my goal is achieved. Still, I have no explanation for this strange behaviour.